# Google Sheets - Arrayformula with textjoin

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to make my arrayformula with textjoin to work, but I'm kind of lost.

[image]

What should be done is that F3 to F5 should have a formula attached, so it displays as showed. The formula need to check for the Payment in column E, date in cell E1, to match with corresponding order from column B & C.

My formula looks as following right now:

'=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF(Orders!C:C = "Visa";Orders!A:A;"")))

I don't know how to also account for the date in cell E1.

Any Google Sheets pro's out there who could help me out in a direction?

Would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include another statement in your IF:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(((Orders!C:C = "Visa")*(Orders!B:B=E1)),Orders!A:A,"")))
```

We use the `*` character because we cannot have `AND` when using the arrayformula